# unable to take input as a tuple of integers( with one line of code)

Tags: python, input, integer, tuples, typecasting-operator

i want the user to input in form a,b
and take that as (a,b) where a,b are integers

I tried

```
c = tuple(int((input("enter tup").split(",")))
```

i understand why this is a error.The only way i am able to do this is

```
 c = (input("enter tup").split(",")
 c = [int(x) for x in c]
 c = tuple(c)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a single line? It will be harder to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.split()` creates a list, and the intermediate list being created on the second line isn't necessary. Since you said you were looking for a one-liner specifically, you can do the following:

```py
c = tuple(int(x) for x in (input("enter tup").split(",")))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate:

```
c = tuple(map(int, input("enter tup").split(",")))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your one liner code :

```
c = tuple(map(int ,input("enter tuple").split()))
```